# Solr indexing: date field with (empty) no value

Tags: solr, field

I have the following field definition in my SOlr Schema

```
name="DvdReleaseDate"   type="date "  stored="true" required="false"
```

My input xml file contains movie names with DVDReleaseDate. So for brand new releases, this field in empty (aka null)
Now when I am indexing, SOLR was throwing empty value exception.

What are my other alternatives?

Basically, I need to support queries based on DVDRelease date & at the same time, empty values are valid use case.

### Editing my question based on feedback:

I have following in the solr schema

field name="dvdReleaseDate"     type="date"    stored="true" required="false"

Exception details are

HTTP ERROR 400
Problem accessing solr update. 
Reason:     Invalid Date String:''

```
Sep 8, 2011 9:14:22 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Invalid Date String:''
   at org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.parseMath(DateField.java:165)

    at org.apache.solr.schema.TrieDateField.createField(TrieDateField.java:169)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.SchemaField.createField(SchemaField.java:98)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.addField(DocumentBuilder.java:204)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:147)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:77)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1360)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
```

Comment: please post the exception and the DVDReleaseDate field definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When adding the document without dvdReleaseDate, don't include the field in the XML document.
E.g. instead of:

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">123</field>
    <field name="dvdReleaseDate"></field>
  </doc>
</add>
```

do:

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">123</field>
  </doc>
</add>
```

Comment: Thanks. This work-around works. However, SOLR is allowing blank/empty field values for other field types. Not sure why this restriction on date field type.

Comment: I have empty field for other SOLR fields i.e. movie_plot is defined as string & sometimes I am finding a string & sometimes empty in my input xml file. My indexing was running fine for empty string fields. This is the reason, I said it looks like a workaround.

Comment: @satya: having an empty string value in a field is not the same as having the field missing in a document. It's like a null in relational databases.

Comment: In both cases i.e. empty & Null cases, 
my XML looks like
   <plot />
  <dvdReleaseDate/>
SOLR indexing  Ok for plot & failing for dvdReleaseDate

Comment: @satya: not the same. null == missing field. Anything else is an actual value, even for strings.